# Maclaurin Series for $\arctan(x)$ by successive differentiation

Tags: derivatives, power-series

I am trying to find a Maclaurin Series for $\arctan(x)$ up to the term with the fifth power of x and I have to use the method of successive differentiation. I know (from an example in my notes) the series found by integration of the $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ series is $$x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}$$ When I try with successive differentiation, I cannot get this same series. Are both series correct, or is it a methodical error on my part? I checked the derivatives using WolframAlpha, so I can't see it being computational.

BY SUCCESSIVE DIFFERENTIATION:
To find coefficients of the power series, evaluate the function and it's successive derivatives at $x=0$:

$\arctan(0) =0$

$\arctan^{(1)}(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}$ so $\arctan^{(1)}(0)= 1$

$\arctan^{(2)}(x) = -2x(1+x^2)^{-2}$ so $\arctan^{(2)}(0)= 0$

$\arctan^{(3)}(x) = (6x^2-2)(1+x^2)^{-3}$ so $\arctan^{(3)}(0) = -2$

$\arctan^{(4)}(x) = -24x(x^2-1)((1+x^2)^{-4}$ so $\arctan^{(4)}(0) = 0$

$\arctan^{(5)}(x) = 24(5x^4-10x^2+1)(1+x^2)^{-5}$ so $\arctan^{(5)}(0) = 24$

Which leads to the series

$$x-2x^3+24x^5-\cdots$$

which captures the alternation of the series but the coefficients are all off. If this is correct and there are indeed the two series, an explanation of this oddity would be much appreciated, though I don't see how this can be the case.

Comment: Sorry, first attempt at the MathJax formatting stuff. I will try to fix it ASAP

Comment: I think I got it now...somebody else tried to edit it while I was working, thanks to whoever that was.

Comment: I was trying, but it looks OK. See my answer.

Comment: An alternative answer to this question is at the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4659000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're simply forgetting to divide by the factorials, as far as I can see. That is, you have $-2$ when you should be getting $$\frac{-2}{3!}=-\frac 1 3$$

You have $24=4!$ when you should be getting $$\frac{4!}{5!}=\frac 1 5$$

and so on.

Recall that the coefficients are given by $$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

There is a nice method to get the derivatives of all orders of $\arctan$: write $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{x-i}-\frac{1}{x+i}\right)$$
and blindly differentiate as if $i\in\Bbb R$. Of course this can be made rigorous.

**ADD** A slick solution is the following:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2k}$$

It follows (by uniqueness of representation) that if $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, $$f^{(2k+1)}(0)=0\; ; \;k\geq 0$$ while $$f^{(2k)}(0)=(-1)^k (2k)!\; ;\; k\geq 0$$

but these are $n$th derivatives of $(\tan^{-1}(x))'$, so are $(n+1)$th derivatives of $\tan^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Oh okay, I had seen that in the derivation of the cos and sin series but thought it had come about somehow as part of the derivation process, which now that I think about it makes no sense at all. Thanks for your help. Stupid mistakes :S

Comment: Ah, I guess I can upvote now (just gained enough rep to be able to). I have accepted your answer. Thanks again!