# Find the $f^{(n)}(0)$ of $\arctan(x)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I wish to solve this by using the method as prescribed here:

https://diendantoanhoc.net/topic/192848-lim-sum-frac2n-12n/?p=742824

$$\arctan(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

The general formula of Maclaurin series is

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

Since both series are equal, their coefficients ought to equal,

So I have

$$\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\left[\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right]n!$$

Something is wrong, the n! shouldn't be there.

Reference from:

https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-f-6-0-where-f-x-arctanx-x

Comment: You have to compare like powers of $x$. The coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$ is $
\frac{{f^{(2n + 1)} (0)}}{{(2n + 1)!}}$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\tan^{-1}x \implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$
So $$f^{n}(x)=D^n(\tan^{-1} x)=\frac{i}{2}D^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$$
Use $$D^{m}(x+a)^{-1}=\frac{(-1)^m m!}{(x+a)^{m+1}}$$
Then $$D^n(\tan^{-1} x)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(x+i)^n}-\frac{1}{(x-i)^n}\right)$$
$$\implies f^{n}(0)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! \sin (n\pi/2)$$

Answer (score 1):

In fact,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1} = x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\cdots = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$$ where $$a_m = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{if $m$ is even,} \\[2mm] \dfrac1m & \textrm{if $m \equiv 1 \!\pmod{\!4}$,} \\ -\dfrac1m & \textrm{if $m \equiv 3 \!\pmod{\!4}.$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: $(-1)^{2n-1}$? Since the positives are odd terms, 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th.

Comment: Also the negatives are odd terms.

Comment: I just deleted 2 comments with $(-1)^{2n}$. Man, I am so dumb and stupid.

Comment: Don't worry. I already wrote the formula in my answer. Recall that $a \equiv b \! \pmod{\! n}$ means that $a=b+\textrm{some multiple of } n$.

Comment: I should study modular arithmetic.

Comment: Man I get your message. I should relearn everything.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the $n$th derivative of $\arctan z$ is
\begin{equation*}
(\arctan z)^{(n)}
=\frac{(n-1)!}{(2z)^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}}.
\end{equation*}
Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\to0}\bigl[(\arctan z)^{(n)}\bigr]
&=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(n-1)!}{(2z)^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}}\\
&=(n-1)!\lim_{z\to0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k-n+1}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}}\\
&=\begin{cases}
0,& \text{$n=2m$}\\
(-1)^{m-1}(2m-2)!, & \text{$n=2m-1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for $m,n\ge1$. In conclusion, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z\to0}\bigl[(\arctan z)^{(n)}\bigr]=(n-1)!\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}, \quad n\ge0.
\end{equation*}

References

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function composited by inverse tangent, square root, and exponential functions*, arXiv preprint (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v2 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2110.08576.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.